# Java Looping for user input error until it's an int/double and distinguishing between the error input

Tags: java, while-loop, user-input

I have a problem I sort of half fixed? It's more of a logic error, I think. My program overall is running smoothly, but I need to fix the flow of how my program interprets user input.

This program should report user error if they input a non numerical value or a negative number. And if the user enters 0, then is should accept it as a correct answer ( I have yet to figure out how to do that since my condition is whether or not it's a double).

I'm trying to differentiate between whether the user inputs a negative number or a character in the feedback. So far, I've made a loop to continuously prompt the user to enter a number if they don't input a double. Though I'm not sure how to go about accepting a 0 as an answer and filtering out negative numbers. I went back to my flow diagram and figured I may need to use an if-else statement to do this. But how can I do that while keeping the loop going? I'm not totally sure how I'm suppose to format that kind of thing.

Help is appreciated for this newbie! Thank you!

```
while(looping){
    // Prompt user to enter how many grades they want averaged
    System.out.println("How many grades would you like to average? ");

    // Check if the input variables are positive numerical variables
    // Or else report to user to input a number
    while(!input.hasNextDouble()) //cannot be negative
        {        
            input.next(); 
            System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        }
            gradeNumber = input.nextInt();

    // Prompt user to enter the grades
    System.out.println("Please enter " + gradeNumber + " grades: ");

    // Use a for-loop to control how many loops - reference to gradeNumber
    for(gradesCount = 0; gradesCount < gradeNumber; gradesCount++){
    // Check if the input variables are numerical variables
    while (!input.hasNextDouble()) 
        {        
            input.next(); 
            System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        }
            gradesInput = input.nextDouble();
            finalGrades = finalGrades + gradesInput;
    } // end loop
```

Comment: A solution is to do endsless loop while(true) {check. read and validate the input if ok you do break;}